# File downloads as html instead of file I want to download, how to fix this?

Tags: java, android

I want to write a download service on android. However when I tried it, it downloads files as HTML not as .jpg for example. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I solved it. Just needed to add authorization key to my website as header. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);    
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

            String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(uri.getEncodedPath(), null, "image/jpeg");
            request.setDescription(filename);
```